# Having two serial keys in postgresql via sqlalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have an unusual challenge. I'm modifying a table to be able to join with two other legacy groups of PostgreSQL tables.

One group pretty much requires that each record in the table have a unique integer. So, the following field definition would work:

> numeric_id = sql.Column(sql.Integer, primary_key=True)

The other group of tables all use UUID fields for the expected JOIN requests. So the following field definition would work:

> uu_account_id = sql.Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True)

But, clearly, I can't have two primary keys. So one of them needs to not be a primary key. It would be nice to simply have both still be automatically assigned when a new record is made.

Any suggestions?

I'm sure I can do a quick hack, but I'm curious if there is a nice clean answer.

(And no: changing the other tables is NOT an option. Way too much legacy code.)

Answer (score 1):

Make the `uuid` column the primary key, like usual.

Define the other column as having `serial` type and `unique`. In SQL I'd write

```
create table mytable (
    mytable_id uuid primary key default uuid_generate_v4(),
    mytable_legacy_id serial unique not null,
    ... other cols ...
);
```

so you just need to do the SQLAlchemy equivalent, whatever that is, of a `not null`, `unique` field.

Note that "serial" is just shorthand for

```
create sequence tablename_colname_seq;
create table tablename (
    colname integer default nextval('tablename_colname_seq'),
    ... cols ...
);
alter sequence tablename_colname_seq owned by tablename.colname;
```

so if you can't make sqlalchemy recognise that you can have a serial field that isn't a primary key, you can do it this way instead.

Answer (score 0):

Between the SQLAlchemy, alembic (which I also use), and PostgreSQL, this turned out to be tricky.

If creating a brand new table from scratch, the following works for my `numeric_id` column:

```
numeric_id = sql.Column(sql.Integer, sql.Sequence('mytable_numeric_id_seq'), unique=True, nullable=False)
```

(It is possible that the `unique=True` and `nullable=False` are overkill.)

However, if modifying an existing table, the sequence itself fails to get created. Or, at least, I couldn't get it to work.

The sequence can be created by hand, of course. Or, if using 'alembic' to make distributed migrations easier, add:

```
from sqlalchemy.schema import Sequence, CreateSequence

def upgrade():
    op.execute(CreateSequence(Sequence("mytable_numeric_id_seq")))
```

To the `version` script created by alembic.

Special thanks to Craig for his help.

(Note: most of the SQLAlchemy examples on the net use `db.` as the module alias rather than `sql.`. Same thing really. I used `sql.` simply because I'm using `db.` already for MongoDB.)